# android spinner set tag

Tags: android, tags, spinner

I am developing application. In that i am populating spinner from the database. I got the arrayList which consist of description and code . I need to set the code as tag for each description.  Is there any possibility to add tag for individual items in spinner.

Comment: what adapter do you use?

Comment: try to write your custon adapter.

Comment: is there is any example . sorry i am new

Comment: if you have an adapter, setting the "code" as a tag seems unnecessary. you could just add a method getCode(position) to the adapter and call that when an item is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try simple custom adapter:

```
    public class MySpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

        private Activity context;

        public CitiesSpinnerAdapter(Activity context){
            this.context=context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            RelativeLayout item= (RelativeLayout)context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.<your spinner item layout name>, null); 
//set your data to layout components
            item.setTag(<your tag object>);

            return item;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks . I will try this one as well